# sharing information on windows phone 7 like android's ACTION_SEND

Tags: android, windows-phone-7

i'm trying to port my android application to windows. in android, there is a way to start an activity with the ACTION_SEND flag i.e.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("text/plain");
intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "....");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Subject"))
```

when you do this, a list of applications (i.e. facebook, text messaging, twitter, evernote, etc...) that can receive the passed in information is presented. the user selects one and information can be shared thus.

is there something analogous in windows phone 7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Windows Phone 7 does have something similar. Take a look at [Launchers and Choosers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff769542%28v=vs.92%29.aspx).

With launchers, you can launch another application but you do not get any information back from the newly launched application after it ends. This is similar to startActivity in Android. With choosers, you can receive information back, similar to startActivityForResults. There are a bunch of launchers and choosers available.

Comment: i take it launchers and choosers are only available in wp7 v7.1 (Mango)?

Comment: They are available in 7.0 too.

Answer (score 1):

Windows Phone 7 currenlty includes no publicly available direct equivalent to Androids Intents.

To access system data and to perform certain actions that are built into the core of the OS and require user interaction, it uses [Launchers and Choosers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff769542%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) which can seem similar. It is not possible to create your own ones though.

If you want to add functionality like sharing to Twitter, etc. you'll need to add this functionality to your application.